# Apply an offset to the indices obtained from np.where

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 3d numpy array and I obtain the indices that meet a certain condition, for example:

```
a = np.tile([[1,2],[3,4]],(2,2,2))
indices = np.where(a == 2)
```

To this indices, I need to apply an offset, fo example (0, 0, 1), and view if meet  another condition.

Something like this:

```
offset = [0, 0, 1]
indices_shift = indices + offset

count = 0
for i in indices_shift:
    if a[i] == 3:
       count += 1
```

In this example, with the offset of (0,0,1), the indices looks like:

```
indices = (array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype=int64), array([0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2], dtype=int64), array([1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3], dtype=int64))
```

and I think that adding the offset the results should be something like:

```
indices_shift = (array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype=int64), array([0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2], dtype=int64), array([2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4], dtype=int64))
```

Is there any easy way to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "shift"?  Try to give expected output when you ask a question, as per [mcve].

Comment: By shift I mean an offset. In the example I want to add 1 to the last dimension. I will try to clarify the question.

Comment: What is the expected output when the shifted index is out of range?

Comment: I added to the question.

Comment: But, what's the final desired output after comparing with `3` and everything?

Comment: It will be to count the number of positions that fulfill the condition. I edit again as you suggest.

Comment: Did the posted solution work for you?

Comment: Yes, works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach -

```
idx = np.argwhere(a == 2)+[0,0,1]
valid_mask = (idx< a.shape).all(1)
valid_idx = idx[valid_mask]
count = np.count_nonzero(a[tuple(valid_idx.T)] == 3)
```

Steps :

- Get the indices for matches against `2`. Use [`np.argwhere`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html) here to get those in a nice `2D` array with each column representing an axis. Another benefit is that this makes it generic to handle arrays with generic number of dimensions. Then, add `offset` in a broadcasted manner. This is `idx`.
- Among the indices in `idx`, there would be few invalid ones that go beyond the array shape. So, get a valid mask `valid_mask` and hence valid indices `valid_idx` among them.
- Finally index into input array with those, compare against `3` and count the number of matches.